# Evaluating $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{11}}{12z^{12}-4z^9+2z^6-4z^3+1}dz$ using Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate 
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{11}}{12z^{12}-4z^9+2z^6-4z^3+1}dz$$
Using Rouche's theorem, I know that all zeros of $12z^{12}-4z^9+2z^6-4z^3+1$ are inside $|z|=1$, but computing the residues seems to be challenging. Is there an easy way to proceed that I am not seeing?

Comment: Substitute $z=1/w$. And forget these zeros...

Comment: Rouche can tell you that zeroes exist inside of a loop but it is not particularly useful for residue calculations since it cannot tell you where exactly the zeroes are. (You probably could do this via an iterative approach, but that's *a lot* of work.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{11}}{12z^{12}-4z^9+2z^6-4z^3+1}dz=\int_{|z|=R>1}\frac{z^{11}}{12z^{12}-4z^9+2z^6-4z^3+1}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i}{12+O(1/R)}d\theta =\frac{\pi}{6}i$ as we let $R \to \infty$

(the first equality crucially uses the fact that the zeroes are inside the unit circle - note also that substitution $z=1/w$ as suggested by @metamorphy works though one has to be careful as it changes the orientation of the unit circle so we get a double minus like in real variables - one from $dz$ and one from getting back to the usual orientation)